# how to add katex plugin into gatsby-theme-blog

Tags: gatsby, katex

I'm new in Gatsby (and Front-end in general).
I am trying to add katex plugin https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-katex/ into my project based on blog theme https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-theme-blog/ but it's not working.

What I did was as follows:
starting from `gatsby-theme-blog`

```
$ gatsby new my-themed-blog https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog-theme
$ cd my-themed-blog
```

and at the top of the project, install `gatsby-remark-katex` plugin,

```
$ npm install --save gatsby-transformer-remark gatsby-remark-katex katex
```

add the config in the top level `gatsby-config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-theme-blog`,
      options: {},
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-katex`,
            options: {
              // Add any KaTeX options from https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/blob/master/docs/options.md here
              strict: `ignore`
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
  // Customize your site metadata:
  siteMetadata: {
    // ... cutting the following
  },
}
```

and import css in the top level `gatsby-browser.js` as

```
import "katex/dist/katex.min.css"
```

and if I put some markdown doc under `content/posts` like

```
---
title: Hello World (example)
date: 2019-12-18
---

math $x + y = \epsilon$.
```

the web page shows just like

```
Hello World (example)
December 18, 2019

math $x + y = \epsilon$.
```

I did it for the plain gatsby project as well as the blog starter https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/
like starting from

```
$ gatsby new gatsby-starter-blog https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog
```

edit `gatsby-config.js` like

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 590,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
            options: {
              wrapperStyle: `margin-bottom: 1.0725rem`,
            },
          },
          `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
          `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files`,
          `gatsby-remark-smartypants`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-katex`,
            options: {
              // Add any KaTeX options from https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/blob/master/docs/options.md here
              strict: `ignore`
            }
          }
        ],
      },
    },
```

and `gatsby-browser.js`

```
// custom typefaces
import "typeface-montserrat"
import "typeface-merriweather"

import "katex/dist/katex.min.css"
```

and it's working.

How can I add the katex plugin into the project using theme like blog-theme? Should I add it into the theme directory in `node_modules` somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat as you (new to gatsby, react and front-end dev) and faced a similar issue with katex not working for me. I found my issue was that I had 2 sections for

```
resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
```

in my `gatsby-config.js` file. I see you've pasted part of your `gatsby-config.js` file so I can only speculate what the remainder of that file contains.

Either way, my old `gatsby-config.js` version looked like this:

```
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",    //----->FIRST ENTRY
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-katex",
            options: {
              // Add any KaTeX options from https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/blob/master/docs/options.md here
              strict: "ignore"
            }
          }
        ],
      },

<****** OTHER PLUGINS IN BETWEEN ********>

    {
      resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",   //------>SECOND ENTRY
      options: {
        excerpt_separator: `<!-- end -->`,
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
            options: {
              maxWidth: 690
            }
          },
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe"
          },
          "gatsby-remark-prismjs",
          "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files",
          "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers"
        ]
      }
    },
```

I figured this might be the only thing causing the issue so I consolidated those 2 into a single `gatsby-transformer-remark` section:

```
{
      resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",
      options: {
        excerpt_separator: `<!-- end -->`,
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-katex",
            options: {
              strict: "ignore"
            }
          },
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
            options: {
              maxWidth: 690
            }
          },
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe"
          },
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-prismjs",
            options: {
              classPrefix: "language-",
              inlineCodeMarker: null,
              aliases: {},
              showLineNumbers: false,
              noInlineHighlight: false,
            },
          },
          "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files",
          "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers"
        ]
      }
},
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your comment.
I thought the similar cause for this. Actually "theme" has its own `gatsby-config.js` (in `node_modules` after installing it) so the top level `gatsby-config.js` is not the only place how the site is configured.
For `gatsby-theme-blog`, there are two `gatsby-config.js` like
`node_modules/gatsby-theme-blog/gatsby-config.js` and `node_modules/gatsby-theme-blog-core/gatsby-config.js` but there is no `gatsby-transformer-remark` entry.
And I think files under `node_modules` are not the right place to edit...

Comment: Ideally, you should never change anything in the node_modules folder since they're the library files. You should use component shadowing instead.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem here is: `gatsby-starter-blog` is configured to render blogs located in `content/blog/<subdir>` folder.

In order to render a markdown blog post, you need to have a blog post template, which is `src/templates/blog-post.js`.

Generating HTML pages from the markdown takes place in `gatsby-node.js` file.

None of these configurations exist in `gatsby-starter-blog-theme`, and hence, the output id different from what you expect.

You can make it work by either using `gatsby-starter-blog`, or by copying the missing files in `gatsby-starter-blog-theme` from this repo: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog.

It isn't KaTeX's problem.  I think the files needed to render does not exist as of now, or they are empty.

I would also recommend you watch the "Build a Blog with React and Markdown using Gatsby" by Taylor Bell.  You can find it here: https://egghead.io/lessons/gatsby-install-the-latest-version-of-gatsby which is a very short series of tutorials which would help you get everything from start to finish.

Comment: thanks for your answer! it seems the way you mentioned is the "starter" approach rather than "theme" mechanism, and I've just found new (?) tutorial doc for ["Building a Theme"](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/building-a-theme/) and the corresponding [egghead videos](https://egghead.io/courses/gatsby-theme-authoring) ... it's already overwhelming to me. Is there any (easy) way to modify existing theme?

Comment: @kengo yes, you can modify any existing theme.  If you want to change the way the page looks, but not modify the "components" (think of it as lego blocks), then you have to change the CSS file.
If you want to add, remove or modify any UI component (same, the lego blocks), you have to modify the blog post template.
In any case, I think you should invest some time behind learning basic React and Gatsby before proceeding.